# printing the number of times an attack occured each day from a syslog file using python

Tags: python

I've got a syslog file named `auth` and I would like to print out the number of times an attack has occurred each day.

I'm under the impression that the date is the key to achieving this. I'm considering inserting one date (Jan 08) for each time an attack has occurred on that day into the dictionary and then repeating this process for consecutive days, followed by a few simple `if` statements to display the days + count.

Is that the right way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
attacks = defaultdict(int)
for line in logfile:
    date = extract_date_from_line(line)
    attacks[date] += 1
```

Every time you assign a value to a key that doesn't exist yet, `defaultdict` doesn't throw a `KeyError` exception like a normal `dict` would; instead, it creates a new key with a default value (in the case of `int` it's `0` which suits us perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is fairly large then a MapReduce job may be the way to go. This can be run on amazons EC2 network. MapReduce is a distributed approach to data processing. You write a mapper(In your case this will parse the file/s and extract the date as the key value and any other field you like as the value) and a reducer which preforms an action on all the values associated with a given key. In your case this would be to find the total amount. MapReduce jobs are usually written in java from what Ive seen but other languages like python are supported.